# How can I easily see only new warnings in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I work on an old large codebase with thousands of existing warnings.  It's common for me to let new ones sneak by because of this.  Does anyone know of a setting, or maybe a plugin that would show only new warnings?

Comment: If you ever find out, please let me know :) I craved that feature a thousand times till now.

Comment: My approach was to bite the bullet and fix all the warnings, after disabling those I don't find very important.

Comment: Marko is correct (theoretically, at least). You should fix whatever warnings you can. The warnings with only 1 or 2 occurrences should be fixed manually, and any other warnings can be fixed by using the `Quick Fix` tool. If there are any left over you should add them to the ignore list in `Preferences`.

Comment: Agreed, and we do fix warnings that we come across. Although we have all introduced bugs from it, so we've become weary to just apply quick fixes to warnings that we aren't 100% sure about. Basically, until one of us gets assigned to "Reduce number of compiler warnings", it's not going to go away. I posted a workaround solution.  Still hoping for something better though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable solution, although it is not perfect.  You can actually delete the warnings themselves before you start coding. In the "Problems" tab, right click on "Warnings" and select "Delete".

Now you only see new ones you introduce, for the most part. So far I have found two caveats:

1. If you do a clean, they all come back.
2. Every time you save a file, it will rebuild it. Existing warnings in the file will reappear.

I'm still hoping for a better solution, so I'm going to hold off on marking this solved.

Comment: Admittedly, this is only a partial workaround. Please come back if you find something better. For example I'd like to find new (deprecation) warnings whenever I upgrade the dependency, but Eclipse will always do a full recompile in this case...

Answer (score -2):

GO TO TASKS IN MENU BAR-> CONFIGURE CONTENTS THERE YOU WILL SEE WARNING ON SELECTION AND ERRORS/WARNING ON SELECT CONFIRM THAT BOTH ARE SELECTED ON SELECTED ELEMENTS AND ITS CHIOLDREN
THEN OK

Comment: PLEASE RESPECT THE PROPER SENTENCE CASE IN YOUR ANSWER. THANK YOU ON BEHALF OF MY EYES.